# Cannot retrieve the picture from s3 bucket using Minio (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, minio

I am trying to retrieve an image from a S3 bucket (hosted on Digital Ocean). The image is found and ready to be retrieved, but I get the following error: **Unhandled Exception: type 'XmlDeclaration' is not a subtype of type 'XmlElement?' in type cast**.

The code:

```dart
static Future initialize() async {
  _bucketExists = await _minio.bucketExists(_bucketName); // returns true

  await _minio.fGetObject(_bucketName, 'path/to/image.png', "download/to/image.png");
}
```

Using the `minio` package (https://pub.dev/packages/minio).

Comment: You can use presigned url to display the images