# How can I retrieve images from digital ocean s3 using Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I have been trying to retrieve images from digital ocean using 2 packages: dospace (https://pub.dev/packages/dospace) and minio(https://pub.dev/packages/minio).

I had issues with both. Issue with Minio I described here, and got no response - [Cannot retrieve the picture from s3 bucket using Minio (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831284/cannot-retrieve-the-picture-from-s3-bucket-using-minio-flutter) .

The problem with Dospace is that when I try to install it I get the error **Because no versions of hive match >2.0.4 <3.0.0 and hive 2.0.4 depends on crypto ^3.0.0, hive ^2.0.4 requires crypto ^3.0.0.
And because every version of dospace depends on crypto ^2.0.6, hive ^2.0.4 is incompatible with dospace.
So, because fauna depends on both hive ^2.0.4 and dospace ^0.12.12, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fauna depends on both hive ^2.0.4 and dospace ^0.12.12, version solving failed.)** Since a lot of my packages are depended on crypto ^3.0.0, I cannot just regress the version of crypto.

So, if none of the libraries work, how can I actually retrieve the image from digital ocean in Flutter?